# lookupTransform - builtin_interfaces/Time to tf2::TimePoint?

Tags: ros2, c++, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd like to use the header stamp in a call to lookupTransform and assume that a conversion would happen automatically, but I'm getting `no matching function call` build errors.  Is there a header to include that will handle this, or is it not implemented yet and I have to convert it manually?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/309953/lookuptransform---builtin_interfaces/time-to-tf2::timepoint?/) by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 8729 on 2018-12-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The manual conversion:

```
builtin_interfaces::msg::Time time_stamp = msg->header.stamp;
tf2::TimePoint time_point = tf2::TimePoint(
    std::chrono::seconds(time_stamp.sec) +
    std::chrono::nanoseconds(time_stamp.nanosec));
geometry_msgs::msg::TransformStamped tf = buffer_.lookupTransform(
    frame1, frame2, time_point)
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2018-12-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use these functions form `tf2_ros/buffer_interface.h`:

- TimePoint to builtin_interfaces::msg::Time

`inline builtin_interfaces::msg::Time toMsg(const tf2::TimePoint & t)`

- builtin_interfaces::msg::Time to TimePoint

`inline const tf2::TimePoint& fromMsg(const builtin_interfaces::msg::Time & time_msg)`

---

Originally posted by [ahcorde](https://answers.ros.org/users/50386/ahcorde/) with karma: 421 on 2019-12-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2